# Testing before publishing for review

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I can't find info how to test an app on Google Marketplace before actually submit it for review. Also I can't figure out how to recognize the domain and the user who is accessing our app from the Navigation bar at Google. On the [Publish page](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing)'s exmple, I see a `web_url` param under `launch` but how to provide in this URL the user's ID of the person clicking on the link? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: When saying **test**, are you referring to the alpha/beta test? Also, can you elaborate on this part **how to recognize the domain and the user who is accessing our app from the Navigation bar at Google**. With regards to the `web_url`, it's function is already stated as **The `web_url` string in the app section of the manifest defines the actual URL used to launch your app**, are you looking for a different behavior?

Comment: @KENdi, thanks I found the `Test install flow` link on top of the Configuration page of the Marketplace API. So this is all set. But I still can't understand where `web_url` is visible. I've set the Universal navigation extension and this URL seams to be used to access our app from the 9 dot menu.